# The name 'Peppa' is the diminutive of what name?

Tags: names, diminutives

Is Peppa or Pippa the diminutive of Josephine? Or is it the diminutive of another name?

Comment: The most famous [Pippa of the moment](https://g.co/kgs/ubvTBp) is named _Philippa_.

Comment: i made a mistake i was refering most to 'Peppa pig' :D the children series , if Peppa is josephine

Comment: All the Pippas I have known (I can think of 4) have been Philippas. Whereas I don't believe I've come across "Peppa" as a name for anything but that pig, I always assumed it was coined for her.

Comment: In English the diminutive for Joseph is Joe; we don't associate the syllable 'Pep' with Joseph or Josephine as Spanish speakers do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the children in *Peppa Pig* (including all of Peppa's closest friends) are alliterative, so we can assume that either:

- her full name is Peppa (I know young humans whose official names are normally regarded as contractions)

or

- it's short for something beginning *P*. I can't think of a likely example that doesn't begin with *Ph* but considering Suzy Sheep this doesn't rule out something like Phillipa.

I tend towards the former interpretation.

The exceptions I can think of are George, Cousin Chloe, and Baby Alexander, all members of Peppa's family.

Peppa isn't a common (nick)name in real life, so I doubt there's a good out-of-universe answer. It is [apparently](http://www.bounty.com/pregnancy-and-birth/baby-names/baby-name-search/p/peppa) a real name in full though I've never met one and can't find a famous example.

Comment: I really hope my daughter is growing out of that show. I know it too well

Comment: 'young humans'? You've revealed yourself, Dark Lord. The enthelators have been released. You should just relax and accept the inevitable oblivion.

Comment: ' ... we can assume that either ...' and 'I tend towards the former interpretation' do not show the objectivity required in ELU answers. Supporting references are needed.